# Laravel Service Provider Still Registering In If Statement

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a few issues with registering a Laravel service provider. In the sense that the service provider is always gets registered, even when it shouldn't.

I'm using `composer require laravel/telescope --dev` and looking at their docs. You can do an if statement within `AppServiceProvider.php` to allow this to register on occasion, in this sense I want only to register if the app has debug enabled.

I created the method.

```php
protected function hasDebug()
{
   return config('app.debug');
}
```

This returned whether or not debug is set within the env. I then have the following if statement within my register method.

```php
public function register()
{
    if ($this->hasDebug()) {
        $this->app->register(TelescopeServiceProvider::class);
    }
}
```

However, even when I have not enabled debugging (I can see this by doing `dd($this-hasDebug())` it will return false. Everything to do with Telescope is being provided. I can still access routes, whereas realistically I do not want to be able to access anything to do with Telescope.

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who is having this issue, this is how to correct it.

The issue was to do with auto discovery within composer. It was always picking up Telescope therefore always registering it.

Although all of the logic was correct within my `AppServiceProvider` because it was registering it was basically ignored.

Inside of `composer.json`, I added this...

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
            "laravel/telescope"
        ]
    }
},
```

Answer (score -1):

Change "app.debug" to APP_DEBUG.  The config helper pulls the mappings directly from your .env file.

Comment: No, it doesn't. `config('app.debug')` looks for the key `'debug'` in the file `config/app.php`. That key, by default, is set to `env('APP_DEBUG')`.

Comment: Sorry, got it confused with the env helper.

Comment: Setting up a couple tests on my end.  I'll get back to you in a couple minutes.